# How to automate multiple user login in selenium java?

Tags: java, selenium

I have a website where one user logs in and waiting for customer orders. There are five different users I need to automate the login part for all the users and need to wait with each user session. But when I tried to login this site with another user, website opens with previous user session. Is there a way with selenium java to done this automation (I am a beginner to selenium automation).
Thanks.

Comment: Can you access the session cookies? You will possibly have to wait for the cookie to become invalid, refresh the page and find out if the user was logged out. The session cookie may tell you when the session will be closed automatically (if not, log out explicitly).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Include your browser initialization inside the login method. so every it will open a new browser and entering the credentials. please share your code samples for more info.